# Identify different user machines on web server side

Tags: webserver, webclient, user-agent, identification

I've done some reading on [User-agent attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-agent-attributes-971230)
and even [client-side exploits](http://ha.ckers.org/weird/) to recover user information.

I want to know if it is possible to legally identify a web client running on a specific computer (not smart phone) as a unique device using the currently available web browsers.

Comment: With cookies, you can attempt to track browser instances. Though there has been a legal act in the EU that declares that the use of cookies must be clearly stated on a webpage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use cookies personally, but if you want to give a computer/browser an ID:

```
$id = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']);
```

This will create a unique md5 sum based off the IP address and user agent, so even using a different browser on the same machine will give you a different ID. You could use this ID to store information in a database or file.

The question doesn't specify a language so I've used PHP for my example, but the principle is the same as with other languages anyway.